# Does AIR run on XP embedded?

Tags: windows-xp, air, embedded, windows-xp-embedded

I cant seem to find any answer to this, other than a series of forum posts asking the same question going unanswered.

Does AIR 2.0 run on XP embedded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES it works!

Received the box today, installed air runtime, installed app no issues. I guess it must be well set up image.

Comment: Perhaps you can add a bit more information to this answer by mentioning what device "the box" is, and how the image is set up?

Comment: sure when I go in later this week I'll grab the details.

Comment: is there a log / config file that would be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No. Some people have done it. Others say no. I think you will have to try it yourself. If stability is important maybe you should get different hardware or move away from an AIR based application.

Comment: Ok thanks. Moving away from AIR is not an option at the moment but OS, maybe for the time being we will run it as a w7 box

Comment: It works great out of the box! The image the box came with must be well set up.